# jquery.Lazy not loading all the images on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, lazy-loading

I am using Lazy with groups of many (> 200) images. The html code for the images is built after many asyncrounous functions are called (a promise is activated when everything is ready).

Lazy seems to work , the first images are loaded when scrolling, but sometimes only the images till a certain number are loaded, the following ones remain without loading.

This happens particularly in a leaflet popup: only the first lines of images below the visible part are loaded when scrolling, the other are never loaded.

It happens in both chromium and firefox

[image: popup]

Apparently the number of images which are loaded is tied to the value of the `threshold` Lazy parameter.

My Lazy's invocation:

```
$(function() {
    $(selector).Lazy(
        {
            autoDestroy: true,
            chainable: false,
            threshold: 20
        }
    );
});
```

The code of one image worked out by Lazy but not loaded:

```
<div id="popup-img-_f-diocesi-eventi_giun-ingresso_giun_virgo_potens_2019--ingresso_giun_virgo_potens_2019-02-23-17_00_05_jpg_1556911864" class="thumb-and-caption-container popup-img-00444311103666667-000885614966666667" style="width: 250px; margin-right: 7.5px; margin-bottom: 7.5px;">
  <div class="thumb-container" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;">
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <img title="albums/Diocesi/Eventi Giun/Ingresso Giun Virgo Potens 2019/Ingresso Giun Virgo Potens 2019-02-23--17.00.05.jpg" alt="Ingresso Giun Virgo Potens 2019-02-23--17.00.05" data-src="cache/08/1/diocesi-eventi_giun-ingresso_giun_virgo_potens_2019-ingresso_giun_virgo_potens_2019-02-23-17.00.05.jpg-250ts.jpg" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="lazyload-popup-media thumbnail" height="250" width="250" mediahash="#!/_f-diocesi-eventi_giun-ingresso_giun_virgo_potens_2019/ingresso_giun_virgo_potens_2019-02-23-17.00.05.jpg" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;">
  </div>
  <div class="media-caption">Ingresso</div>
</div>
```

the src attribute remains with the default Lazy's 1px x 1px gif.

No error is shown in the console.

The weird thing it then that, pressing twice f12, i.e. opening and closing the developer tools, the images are loaded.

I cannot make a jsfiddle, but I can show the issue:

- [click here](https://palmaro.qumran2.net/#!/_f-azione_cattolica)
- then click on the position icon in the top line (a map opens)
- then click on the 243 marker

A popup with many images is shown, scrolling you see the thumbnail that are not loaded, and you get them loaded hitting twice F12.

Comment: it would be useful to provide a fiddle or sth similar to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add an `appendScroll` to your Lazy invocation, as explained in [this example: Elements inside a container](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/example_elements-inside-a-container).

So add `appendScroll: $('#popup-images-wrapper')` to your config – or whatever the selector of your scroll box is.

The thing is: by default Lazy listens to the scroll event of `window`, but in your case nothing scrolls on `window`, since you are on a fullscreen map. So you have to tell on which element Lazy should listen for scroll events.